# Launching IoT Core app using protocol activation

Tags: c#, powershell, uwp, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am currently developing an IoT Core app that should be only launched with protocol activation. For debugging purposes I ran it on a full version of Windows 10, and from there launching an app using protocol is easy with `explorer.exe`.

I completely forgot, that there is no `explorer.exe` on IoT Core OS, and hence my question - is there any other way of launching an IoT UWP app on this OS using protocol launch? Like maybe remote PowerShell command to execute to do this?

The reason I am using protocol launch is that I will be running another app on full Windows 10 and there needs to be some information provided to the IoT Device before the app could open. The solution has to have the possibility to launch from C# code, so any IoT Device Hub solution will not suffice.

Comment: Are you finding this:["Launch an app on a remote device"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-a-remote-app)?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT As far as I understand, this solution shows how to launch this from another UWP app (package manifest, using `Windows.System.RemoteSystems` lib, etc.), but I seem to need to use standard .Net libraries. I tried adding the `Windows.*` libs as described [here](http://www.davidmoore.info/blog/2014/10/17/walkthrough-using-winrt-libraries-from-a-windows-desktop-application/) but specifying `10.0` as target version, but there is a problem in first line of BuildDeviceList method - the awaited method has no GetAwaiter method.

Comment: Also, I was able to sniff the HTTP Request using Fiddler, that allowed me to launch the app from C# using `HttpWebRequest`, but this doesn't allow me to send any data to the app for it to use.

Comment: For windows iot core, UWP apps are its primary app type and it is easy to [launch another UWP app from a UWP app and exchange data between the two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results). Currently, there is no such command for starting the app and exchanging data from PowerShell.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT If I create a headless UWP app on IoT running a Rest server will I be able to run my main UWP app from there using protocol? So that the request path would look like this: 
`[main win32 app] ----rest api call---> [rest server] ----protocol launch---> [main UWP app]`?